# Does VPN on app and router result in double encryption?

Tags: vpn

I have a VPN installed on my router and it is permanently connected to a city (City A).

I also have a VPN app on my laptop. If I am connected to the WiFi on my VPN-enabled router and use the app on my laptop to connect to a different city (City B) will that then mean my data is double encrypted?

I’m wondering if there’s any security benefit of using the VPN app whilst already connected to a VPN router.

Comment: It will depend on how everything is configured

Comment: Both using open vpn (UDP), connected to the same country but different servers. All traffic on the router goes through the VPN, same for the laptop app. Both router and VPN app have kill switch enabled.

Comment: It's most likely double encrypted. There's little to no security benefit. There might be a privacy benefit.

Comment: Most likely, yes, it double-encrypts. Your data is encrypted and redirected to city B, encrypted again and redirected to city A, then at city A it gets decrypted and goes to its original destination of city B, then at city B it gets decrypted and goes to its original destination. Congratulations - you made your own [onion routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onion_routing) (but the VPN in both cities still knows who you are because you're logged in).